# PHP login script without database - different page redirections

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP so pardon my lack of knowledge. Currently I have a PHP login script where it is without a database. I tested out with only one username and password and it works perfectly fine. However, I need to add another set of username and password and they should redirect to different pages.

PHP Login Script:

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

    /* Check Login form submitted */    
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        /* Define username and associated password array */
        $logins = array('Username1' => '123456', 'ReadOnly' => '1234567');

        /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

        /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
            /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
            $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
            $_SESSION['start'] = time(); // Taking logged in time.
            $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5400*60);
            // Ending a session in an hour from the starting time.
            header("location:index.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
            $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Script in the page it is redirected to:

```
<?php 
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start(); /* Starts the session */

if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
  header("location:login.php");
}
  else {
        $now = time(); // Checking the time now when home page starts.

        if ($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
            session_destroy();
            echo "Your session has expired! <a href='http://localhost/PortalV4/login.php'>Login here</a>";
        }
        else { //Starting this else one [else1]

?>
```

Currently, it only redirects to index.php with the username 'Username1' and password '123456'. I need a different page redirect using the username 'ReadOnly' and password '1234567' to readOnly.php. How can I compare the different usernames and passwords and redirect to different pages?

Comment: I have lot of questions, So you need to achieve Username1 to index.php and rest of all the users to other index2.php ? right? and Highly recommend to use Database if you are going to add more users.

Comment: @AjmalPraveen Yup that is correct. I would love to use a database but unfortunately the company i'm making the webpage for is unable to install a database for me due to security reasona

Comment: OH bad.. But i can see down there someone given you a solution you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the target url as part of the logins array:

```
$logins = [
    'Username1' => 
        [
             'pass'       =>'123456',
             'destination'=>'index.php',
        ],
    'ReadOnly' => 
        [
             'pass'       =>'1234567',
             'destination'=>'read-only.php',
        ]
    ];

    /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
    if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username]['pass'] == $Password){
        //session stuff here then
        header("location:" . $logins[$Username]['destination']);
```